# Program Automator to set FOCUS (do not disturb/sleeping/work) during scheduled meetings within iCal

Tags: automator, ical, do-not-disturb

I'm looking to somehow have my MacBook go into do not disturb or the new updated "focus" mode upon certain Scheduled events. I've put tag's in the notes of the events that I want to trigger FOCUS and I've set up the Automator app thus far, but there is no option for focus settings. The goal is to trigger focus once an event starts or an allotted time before it.

[image: automator example]

Is there any way to program in a focus setting's pane or other workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post. I see it got no responses. I wondered if you ever figured anything out. I was trying to do the same thing. I finally gave up on it and did something else. Instead of having Calendar trigger Focus, I have Apps triggering it. This has the added benefit of turning on Focus for impromptu meetings that are not on my schedule.

What I did was use the schedule function in Focus. I went into System Settings, Focus, and then clicked on Work. Then I went to Add Schedule and selected App. Then I added, Zoom, Slack, and Microsoft Teams. When those apps are being used, Focus automatically turns on.

I hope this helps if you even get it.

Comment: I ended up doing the exact same thing. Would be ideal if Apple added the feature to their Calendar app. Thanks for answering either way!